# Counting Folder Depth with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, calculated-columns, powershell-4.0

**1. Code Description** *alias how it is intended to work*

User enters a path to a directory in PowerShell. Code checks if any folder within the declared directory contains no data at all. If so, the path of any empty folder will be shown on the prompt to the user and eventually removed from the system.

---

**2. The Issue** *alias what I am struggling with*

The code I just wrote doesn't count the depth of a folder hierarchy as I would expect (the column in the output table is blank). Besides that, the program works okay - I've still got to fix the issue where my code removes empty parent directories first and child directories later, which of course will cause an error in PowerShell; for instance, take

```
C:\Users\JohnMiller\Desktop\Homework
```

where `Homework` consists of `Homework\Math\School Project` and `Homework\Computer Science\PowerShell Code`. Note that all directories are supposed to be empty with the exception of `PowerShell Code`, the folder containing this script. (Side note: A folder is considered empty when no file dwells inside. At least that's what my code is based on for now.)

---

**3. The Code**

```
# Delete all empty (sub)folders in [$path]

[Console]::WriteLine("`n>> Start script for deleting all empty (sub)folders.")
$path = Read-Host -prompt ">> Specify a path"

if (test-path $path)
{
  $allFolders = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where {$_.PSisContainer -eq $True}
  $allEmptyFolders = $allFolders | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0}
  $allEmptyFolders | Select-Object FullName,@{Name = "FolderDepth"; Expression = {$_.DirectoryName.Split('\').Count}} | Sort-Object -descending FolderDepth,FullName

  [Console]::WriteLine("`n>> Do you want do remove all these directories? Validate with [True] or [False].") #'#
  $answer = Read-Host -prompt ">> Answer"

  if ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean($answer) -eq $True)
  {
    $allEmptyFolders | Remove-Item -force -recurse
  } 

  else
  {
    [Console]::WriteLine(">> Termination confirmed.`n")
    exit
  }
}

else
{
  [Console]::WriteLine(">> ERROR: [$($path)] is an invalid directory. Program terminates.`n")
  exit
}
```

Comment: A more efficient approach is to walk the directory tree manually e.g. [How to use Powershell Pipeline to Avoid Large Objects?](//stackoverflow.com/a/42382153)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The depth-count problem:

Your code references a `.DirectoryName` property in the calculated property passed to `Select-Object`, but the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` have no such property. Use the `.FullName` property instead:

```
$allEmptyFolders | 
  Select-Object FullName,@{Name='FolderDepth'; Expression={$_.FullName.Split('\').Count}} |
    Sort-Object -descending FolderDepth,FullName
```

#### Eliminating nested empty subfolders:

To recap your problem with a simple example:

If `c:\foo` is empty (no files) but has empty subdir. `c:\foo\bar`, your code outputs them *both*, and if you then delete `c:\foo` first, deleting `c:\foo\bar` next fails (because deleting `c:\foo` also removed `c:\foo\bar`).

If you eliminate all nested empty subdirs. up front, you not only declutter what you present to the user, but you can then safely iterative of the output and delete one by one.

With your approach you'd need a 2nd step to eliminate the nested empty dirs., but here's a **depth-first recursive function that omits nested empty folders**. To make it behave the same way as your code with respect to hidden files, pass `-Force`.

```bsh
function Get-RecursivelyEmptyDirectories {

  [cmdletbinding()]
  param(
    [string] $LiteralPath = '.', 
    [switch] $Force, 
    [switch] $DoNotValidatePath
  )

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  if (-not $DoNotValidatePath) {
    $dir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $LiteralPath
    if (-not $dir.PSIsContainer) { Throw "Not a directory path: $LiteralPath" }
    $LiteralPath = $dir.FullName
  }

  $haveFiles = [bool] (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -File -Force:$Force | Select-Object -First 1)

  $emptyChildDirCount = 0
  $emptySubdirs = $null

  if ($childDirs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Directory -Force:$Force) {

    $emptySubDirs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($childDir in $childDirs) {
      if ($childDir.LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink') { 
        Write-Verbose "Ignoring symlink: $LiteralPath"
      } else {
        Write-Verbose "About to recurse on $($childDir.FullName)..."
        try { # If .AddRange() fails due to exceeding the array list's capacity, we must fail too.
          $emptySubDirs.AddRange(@(Get-RecursivelyEmptyDirectories -DoNotValidatePath -LiteralPath $childDir.FullName -Force:$Force))        
        } catch {
          Throw
        }
        # If the last entry added is the child dir. at hand, that child dir.
        # is by definition itself empty.
        if ($emptySubDirs[-1] -eq $childDir.FullName) { ++$emptyChildDirCount }
      }
    } # foreach ($childDir ...

  } # if ($childDirs = ...)

  if (-not $haveFiles -and $emptyChildDirCount -eq $childDirs.Count) {
    # There are no child files and all child dirs., if any, are themselves
    # empty, so we only output the input path at hand, as the highest
    # directory in this subtree that is empty (save for empty descendants).
    $LiteralPath
  } else {
    # This directory is not itself empty, so output the (highest-level)
    # descendants that are empty.
    $emptySubDirs
  }

}
```

---

Tips regarding your code:

- `Get-ChildItem -Directory` is available in PSv3+, which is not only shorter but also more efficient than `Get-ChildItem | .. Where { $_.PSisContainer -eq $True }`.
- Use `Write-Host` instead of `[Console]::WriteLine`
- `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean($answer)` only works with the culture-invariant string literals `'True'` and `'False'` (`[bool]::TrueString` and `[bool]::FalseString`, although case variations and leading and trailing whitespace are allowed).